# Regex match every char but the following

Tags: regex, match

Can you help me to build a regex that match everything but the characters matched by `[a-zA-Z][\w:.-]`?

For example: in the test string `abc)def` the `)` should be a matched char for the final regex.

I tried using several variations of the regex `(?!fox\b)\b\w+` ([see](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions.html)) without any result.

For easy the test you can use [this service](http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/).

Comment: would like the match to be 1 single character, or several consecutive?

Comment: So do you want to match the string, that does not match that pattern?

Comment: @DoesntMatter: Any single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it seems that I overlook the issue.

The answer is:

```
[^a-zA-Z\w:.-]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `[^\w:.-]` would be enough

Answer (score 1):

You can [*negate* a character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I came up with that solution without see this, but I will accept yours for the effort, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If this is javascript, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function match_with_space(str) {
    return str.match(/[^\w:.-]/g);
}
function match_without_space(str) {
    return str.match(/[^\w\s:.-]/g);
}
</script>
```