# Regex matching a string followed by anything but a certain character

Tags: regex, regex-negation

[Regex match every char but the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665696/regex-match-every-char-but-the-following)
This didn't help me.

I'm trying to match `momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=` followed by anything but `9` in a *gz* file.

These don't match:

```
$zgrep "momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=\[\^9\]" file.gz
$zgrep "momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=\(\^9\)" file.gz
$zgrep "momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=\^\[9\]" file.gz
$zgrep "momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=\^\(9\)" file.gz
```

This does:

```
$zgrep "momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=\(9\)" file.gz
```

I now there're lines in the file containing `momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=89`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply try

`$zgrep "momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=[^9]" file.gz`

if you don't want to match the single `9`.

/edit

If you also need speeds with 2 digits and more, try:

`momentaneousVehicleSpeedKmph=([0-8]|[0-9]{2,})\b`

Comment: Oh, embarrassing! I assumed you had to escape them. Thanks!